# Selenium 2 (WebDriver) and Phpunit?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Any one know how to use Selenium 2 with Phpunit? Are there any Selenium 2 samples in PHP?

Comment: +1 This is a very good question. I wanted to ask it some time ago, because, sorry to say, the Selenium page is not very friendly for PHP users. There is a lot of buzz about WebDriver lately, but I haven't seen those two in action yet.

Comment: PHPUnit supports Selenium2 as of version 3.6 
For details see http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html#selenium.selenium2testcase

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Quick update:** phpunit does now support Selenium 2

- https://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html
- https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/selenium.html

---

At the time of writing, PHPUnit does not support Selenium 2.

[php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) from [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/watir-to-webdriver-unit-test-frameworks/10150314152278920) allows the complete WebDriver API to be called from PHP in an elegant way. To quote:

> Most clients require you to first read the protocol to see what's
>   possible, then study the client itself to see how to call it. This
>   hopes to eliminate the latter step.

It is used by starting up the Selenium 2 server, which provides the interface at `localhost:4444/wd/hub`.

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar
```

then running the PHP test code, which calls that interface. For example:

```
<?php

require '/path/to/php-webdriver/__init__.php';

$webdriver = new WebDriver();

$session = $webdriver->session('opera', array());
$session->open("http://example.com");
$button = $session->element('id', 'my_button_id');
$button->click();
$session->close();
```

The [WebDriver API](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) is mapped to PHP methods, compare calling `click` on `element` in the example with the element/click API call in the documentation.

The test code can then be wrapped in regular phpUnit tests.

This is not native phpUnit support, but it's a quite robust approach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this facebook wrapper. It seems like a lot of commands aren't working such as sendKeys

Comment: Hey Adil! You mean lots of commands aren't working in the _other PHP selenium implementations_, right? That's just another reason to use this one, the architecture inherently makes it complete.

Comment: @cmc: There is nothing in @php-webdriver@ which would make it "inherently complete" (thought it seems fairly easy to add new commands). There is a static list of accepted commands (see the @getMethod()@ functions in the various classes).

Comment: @Tgr: Please kindly refer to the part "Some unavoidable exceptions to direct protocol translation." in [the readme](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver).

Comment: @cmc: that is besides the point. It may be a *direct* translation, but it is not an *automatic* one. `WebDriverElement`, `WebDriverSession` etc. inherit `__call` from `WebDriverBase`, which calls `getHTTPMethod` with the function name (possibly removing `get`/`post`/`delete` from it). `getHTTPMethod` throws an exception if the command name is not found in the array returned by the `methods()` function of the class, which is just a static list of known commands.

Comment: [Depends on your definition of automatic](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/commit/9d236926f556a95df1e9735f80038e5071de5a15) :)

Comment: ... half-kidding with the last comment of course. What I'm saying is: It's real easy to add new commands _because_ the author made everything else automatic and consistent. So it's simply false to say there is "nothing inherently complete" about the framework, because everything is, except the command list and the occasional syntactic sugar. If that really really itches you, just go and clone the thing and give the author a pull request... for me almost automatic is good enough.

Comment: Quick update - phpunit does now support Selenium 2 http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html

Answer (score 8):

please look at the http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/ . This is PHP library that communicates with Selenium Webdriver server using JsonWireProtocol. This is early version but it works.

Comment: There is also this other [Php binding library](https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP). Both libraries seem to be rather active at the moment.

Comment: PHPUnit has its own Selenium library which better mimics the JsonWireProtocol webdriver bindings (http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html). If you want to use the WebDriver one, Facebook's one is more actively supported.

Comment: Last updated for two years. Use the [instaclick/webdriver](https://packagist.org/packages/instaclick/php-webdriver) package instead!

Answer (score 5):

Currently (2017) I recommend using [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), what is AFAIK the most feature complete PHP language binding to interact with Selenium WebDriver.

This library was rewritten in 2014 to support Selenium 2, and its API is mostly based on the official Java WebDriver bindings. This means you can also take advantage of code examples written in Java, as they can be usually simply followed in PHP. Its also written in a modern OOP way and follows standard PSR-4 namespaces and also PSR-2 coding standards.

I would recommend this library over [phpunit-selenium](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium) - as it was originally designed for Selenium 1 (though it nowadays support Selenium 2) and its API is strongly tight to PHPUnit. It also does not support some of the WebDriver features and is not up-to-date with upcomin [W3C WebDriver specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/).

Php-webdriver is on the other hand independent library, but its **integration with PHPUnit** is quite simple - or you can use existing tools like [Steward](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward), which includes all the PHPUnit integration and provide also nice convenience layer and eg. allow to simply run multiple tests in parallel (without a need of another tools like [paratest](https://github.com/brianium/paratest)).

There are also other testing framework integration options mentioned on the [project homepage](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/#testing-framework-integration).

Comment: Timely as I just recently retried the semi-official phpunit-selenium to find the docs are still lacking. Though, getting this one working reliably is also a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

PHPUnit Selenium integration code lives as a separate project in [github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium), as far as I can see it does not support Selenium 2, so the answer to your question would be - No, you can not use Selenium 2 with PHPUnit.

But you can clone the source tree and make it work with Selenium 2.

Comment: For the time being I've settled on using Java for tests. Java's Dbunit is much faster than the PHP port anyway.

Comment: Selenium support comes with PHPUnit: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html

Answer (score 2):

We created a library for that, I hope it helps. It also uses the JSON Wire protocol but we aimed to make it compatible with the examples from other languages, so the syntax would be very similar. Here's the link: https://github.com/Nearsoft/PHP-SeleniumClient

If you like it, share it, improve it or fork it :)

Regards, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

phpunit webdriver bindings are hosted on google code.  There is something we need to understand beyond this.

1. PHPUnit needs to be installed. (Either through PEAR package or download and install manually)
2. PHP IDE such as Eclipse PDT has to be downloaded and installed.
3. Selenium-Stand-Alone server has to be running while executing the WebDriver Selenium test

Comment: why does an IDE need to be installed?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial about how to use Selenium 2, Facebook wrapper, find it here:

http://testigniter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/running-selenium-2-webdriver-using.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommened the usage of [Menta](https://packagist.org/packages/aoemedia/menta), a Selenium 2 Framework which requires [WebDriver](https://packagist.org/packages/instaclick/php-webdriver). Both packages are PSR-0 compatible, so you can use them with Composer. You can configure selenium with the phpunit.xml. Here an example

```
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false"
         strict="true" verbose="true">
    <php>
        <var name="testing.selenium.seleniumServerUrl" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" />
        <var name="testing.selenium.browser" value="firefox" />
        <var name="testing.selenium.windowPosition" value="0,0" />
        <var name="testing.selenium.windowSize" value="1280x1024" />
        <var name="testing.selenium.windowFocus" value="1" />
        <var name="testing.selenium.timeoutImplicitWait" value="10000" />
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Integrationstests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php" phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator=">=">tests/integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

The bootstrap file reads the configuration variables from testing.selenium.*, so you can easily set new variables.

```
<?php

\Menta_ConfigurationPhpUnitVars::addConfigurationFile(__DIR__ . '/../phpunit.xml');

$configuration = \Menta_ConfigurationPhpUnitVars::getInstance();
\Menta_SessionManager::init(
    $configuration->getValue('testing.selenium.seleniumServerUrl'),
    $configuration->getValue('testing.selenium.browser')
);
```

Now you can easily implement you testcases. Here an example

```
<?php

namespace tests\integration;

use WebDriver\LocatorStrategy;

class TestSearch extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testGoogle()
    {
        $session = \Menta_SessionManager::getSession();
        $session->open('http://www.google.de');
        $element = $session->element(LocatorStrategy::NAME, 'q');
        $this->assertTrue($element->displayed());
    }
}
```

The Menta Package also have two demo files, located [here](https://github.com/AOEmedia/Menta/tree/master/Demo)

Answer (score 1):

Today a took a deep jump into Selenium and phpunit.
It is possible and you may find some examples and instructions over here:
http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html

Creator of phpunit got some nice examples of the api.
With a little experimentation and reading the error message, you'll get along.
Havn't found a great library myself as well.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php

As last a tutorial with from nettuts which helps you along the basics:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-selenium-2-with-phpunit/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Selenium 2 (WebDriver)` and `PHPUnit tests` is simple. But May I want to gave you advice that the first you should be try `Selenium IDE` because you need to expect in `selenium command`. If you are expect in `Selenium command` if so `selenium 2 (Webdriver)` and `PHPUnit test` will be more simple for you.

You can try `selenium IDE` tutorials on [here](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/)  and you can learn `selenium 2 (Webdriver) and PHPUnit` at [here](http://www.dragonbe.com/2013/05/ua-testing-with-selenium-and-phpunit.html).

Answer (score 0):

I work on [selenium2php](https://github.com/rnixik/selenium2php). I have too many tests for Selenium1 recorded with Selenium IDE. Now it converts html tests into Selenium2. Actually, for PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase. I am going to implement more commands.