# selenium webdriver: mouseOver and PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, mouseover, webdriver

How can I use action mouseOver() with PHPUnit in my tests?
I can't find information about it.. Only using of java class Action.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Selenium 2 WebDriver is not supported by the existing Selenium extension for PHPUnit (only the deprecated Selenium RC is). Refer to thread [Selenium 2 (WebDriver) and Phpunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206547/selenium-2-webdriver-and-phpunit), it's from a year ago but still valid.

Check [this post](http://css.dzone.com/articles/selenium-2-php-code?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20zones/agile%20%28Agile%20Zone%29) out for alternatives.